Why does popup prevent data from updating in Mapbox
In my React application using react-map-gl, I have a map layer displaying data from a GeoJSON. When I update the GeoJSON with new data, the map displays the new data correctly. However, the old data that is no longer present in the GeoJSON remains visible on the map. I suspect this is because there are popups associated with the old data that are still being referenced, even though the data itself no longer exists. How can I resolve this issue? Should I delete the popups every time I update the GeoJSON, or is there a property in the popup component that can handle this automatically?
Below is the source code for my layer. Could you please review it to see if there is an error, or if the issue lies elsewhere?
<Source
            id="tipi"
            type="geojson"
            data={props.tipigeoJson}
            promoteId="id"
            generateId={true}
            key={JSON.stringify(props.tipigeoJson)} // lign that update layer every time geojson changes
           
          >
            <Layer
              id="tipi"
              type="symbol"
              layout={{
                "icon-image": "Accident_round",
                "icon-size": ["*", 0.05, iconSize],
                
              }}
              
             
            />
          </Source>
  


  {props.tipigeoJson &&
    showPopup &&
    props.tipigeoJson.features.map((feature, index) => {
      
      if (
        feature.properties.score > 3
          &&
          feature.properties.isinfeed === true
      ) {
        return (
          <Popup
            key={index} // Use the index as the key
            longitude={feature.geometry.coordinates[0]}
            latitude={feature.geometry.coordinates[1]}
            offsetTop={[0, -10]}
            closeButton={false}
            closeOnClick={false}
            className="mapboxgl-popup"
          >
          
                <h3>Accident - tipi</h3>
                
          </Popup>
        );
      } else {
        return null; 
      }
    })}


Hi @Charles, could you please add you code again to the edited question.

Thank you Michael, but my code is correct, error came from my geojson. I will use your model for my futures questions !
